# mimic The "to" option in messaging WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to mimic the system's "to" textbox that when you start writing in it , it displays the names and accounts that's associated with the user

I don't know if there's already built in in the development tools or I have to implement it, any ideas ?

Comment: Here is full list of InputScopes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputscopenamevalue(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: You could probably get the same sort of thing using the AutoCompleteBox from the toolkit and the Contacts listing.

Comment: @JasonHaley - agreed, I am afraid this is only solution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend building your own control that is special-purpose built, as opposed to using something like the AutoCompleteBox control from the Toolkit (that is a big challenge to template or customize like your would like to do).

The ACB only offers single selection, while the To: line in Mail/Messaging effectively allows for many items.

Sorry that there isn't anything built into the platform for this.

*Disclaimer: Yes, I wrote the original AutoCompleteBox control for Silverlight, and yes it didn't port well to WP7 (though I did not do that work).*